Explanation of fundamental principle of counting
I was reading a math textbook and I came across the fundamental principle of counting. I understood the principle and also could kind of visualize it in the form of trees, but I can't understand it intuitively. Any help would be appreciated.
Edit: This is another doubt: What exactly do authors mean by independent?

I believe you get the problem when you try to incorporate the number of data with the data itself and its distributions. Try to first focus on the first space or visualize each iteration to be a box or space to be filled. Therefore, when you fill the first box by any singular element from the finite data set that you have, then the next box could be filled using one less that the initial number of data given to you. This can be extended to any finite number of n boxes and n data. For example, assume there are 5 boxes that need to be filled by 6 dataset. The first box can have only one data therefore for the second box from the initial 6 data subtract one (the data reserved in the first box) therefore the second box can be filled by 5 possible data from the data set. If you want a more mathematical way of proof, try to formulate the fundamental principal of counting and use the principle of mathematical induction to prove the same.

Suppose you have to dress and that you can choose from

$a=2$ different shirts
$b=3$ pairs of pants

in how many way can you dress?
Since for any of the $3$  pairs of pants we can choose $2$ different shirts, we have $a\cdot b=3\cdot 2=6$ different ways to dress.
More in general, if an event has $a$ possible outcomes or choices, and another event has $b$ possible outcomes or choices, then the total number of possible unique combinations of outcomes between the two is $a\cdot b$, which is precisely the fundamental principle of counting.

So the multiplication rule is derived from the addition rule? Since if I take the first shirt, I can wear 3 pairs of pants with it and if I take the second shirt, I can wear 3 pairs of pants with it. Mathematically, $13 + 13 = 2*3$

I have seen these examples before, but for some reason I just can't 'get a feel of it'.

@AkshajMishra Yes they are completely equivalent.

I have no idea why I can't get my head around it even though it's completely straightforward.

@AkshajMishra Let try to start with some basic example, also using objects and trying to compine them, just to convince yourserlf!
